# Present modalViewController in Landscape mode using storyboard in IOS 6

Tags: ios6, modalviewcontroller, landscape

I have an app with some views in portrait mode , and I want to present modal view controller in landscape mode... For IOS 5.0 and 5.1 works perfectly, in IOS 6 it open modalView but in portrait mode. You need to know: I use storyboard and I set that VC to Landscape...
In app delegate I added:

```
-(NSUInteger)application:(UIApplication *)application    supportedInterfaceOrientationsForWindow:(UIWindow *)w
{return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskPortrait;}
```

If I add `| UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape`, I am able to rotate the app in other views.

Then for Summary I disabled all supported interface orientation..
Here I tried to set portrait and landscape left , and works well, but in this case all views I can to rotate to left and back to portrait.

After this in ViewCOntroller which I want to lunch in landscape, I have this methods for IOS 6:

```
-(NSUInteger)supportedInterfaceOrientations
{return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft;}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{return YES;}
```

and after running when I tap button to lunch modalView, I get this error: **"Supported orientations has no common orientation with the application, and shouldAutorotate is returning YES"**

I know is about returning YES on that method but if I set NO, nothing happens.
I would like to consider that: my app need to work on IOS 5 and later.

Anybody can help me please ?
Any suggestion is appreciate it ;)

Many thanks

Comment: Hi All,I implement that by adding a new navigation controller (in storyboard) and then present modal by this new nav controller.  Hope you can managing this. Have luck ;)

Answer (score 3):

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
[super viewWillAppear:animated];
[self transformView2ToLandscape];}

-(void) transformView2ToLandscape {

NSInteger rotationDirection;
UIDeviceOrientation currentOrientation = [[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation];

if(currentOrientation == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeLeft){
    rotationDirection = 1;
}else {
    rotationDirection = -1;
}

CGAffineTransform transform = [arController.viewController.view transform];
transform = CGAffineTransformRotate(transform, degreesToRadians(rotationDirection * 90));
[arController.viewController.view setTransform: transform];}
```

This works fine for me.